# Mount drives on timecapsule through SSH

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, time-capsule

Here's the situation:

I have time capsule router/external HD connected to a macpro -- call this remote computer.
I have the time capsule set up with a static IP address so that I am able to access this remote computer via SSH with a macbook pro -- call this local computer -- from outside my LAN.

If I use the finder on remote or local computer and click on the time capsule in the Shared section, I can select a volume that then gets mounted in /Volumes on the computer whose finder I used (both remote and local work).

What I can't do is use the command line to mount the volumes located on the time capsule on the remote computer.
I have tried a variety of mount_afp commands, such as described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291617/mount-sparsebundle-on-a-time-capsule using the static ip address of the time capsule but AFPMountURL fails with either error codes 1 or -1069.

**How can I mount the volumes on the time capsule on the remote computer using the local computer and a static ip address?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved pretty simply once I got a bit more understanding of the processes.
This helped: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131930/how-can-i-access-my-time-capsule-through-ssh

translation of Finder -> connect to server to command line:

`mount_afp afp://user:pass@LANIPaddress/volume mountpoint`

where LANIPaddress can be found by clicking on the time capsule in airport utility and mountpoint is where you want to mount the volume